# Network dropout when wall furnace fan switches speeds

Tags: wiring, network

I have one of those old Williams/Forsaire gas wall furnaces (Forsaire 465fx, to be precise). It's about 8 feet from my network router, with my TV and FireStick in between the two. When the heater is running, it switches its fan between two different speed settings as part of its normal cycle, but often when the fan switches speeds, I experience a brief network dropout, evidenced by the TV/FireStick losing connection to whatever its streaming (both internet streaming services and local LAN streams from my PC experience this dropout).

Thinking it was the old-style blower motor causing voltage drops as it switches load, I rewired the heater to its own circuit breaker, and made sure it was on the other leg/phase from the circuit the router and TV are on, but it still does it. Then I tried buying a battery backup UPS with Automatic Voltage Regulation, and plugged the router and TV into it, thinking it'd compensate for any momentary voltage drops, but it STILL does it.

All the involved network devices (Fire Stick, PC that I stream Steam games from, etc) are hard wired via Cat6 ethernet cables, so I don't think it's a wifi/radio interference issue.

I'm at my wits end trying to track down the cause and fix it.  Anyone have any suggestions for what could be causing it?

Comment: Exactly what kind of router is it?   What kind of internet service do you have (cable/dsl/fibre/satellite/etc) ?   Does the router reboot or reconnect its internet uplink when the furnace clonks ?   Do you use wireless at all?    Can your router have any AP functions outright turned-off?

Comment: It's a Netgear Nighthawk AX6 Router, and Spectrum Cable internet.  The router doesn't reboot, and the dropout is very very brief. By the time the streaming stick has popped up an error message that it was disconnected, its only about 3 to 5 seconds before you can resume the stream and it's back.  I do use wifi for other devices (phones, laptops, etc) but I haven't noticed the dropout on them. I assumed that was because it's brief enough to only interrupt an active data stream, and normal internet browsing activity just automatically re-sends any lost data traffic.

Comment: @Tonyx3 Emphasising part of what Criggie asked: is there a wireless connection between whatever is generating the popup message, and its upstream device (presumably the router)? Are you absolutely certain of your answer, i.e. are you certain that the TV (or whatever) hasn't fallen back to WiFi because even though you wired it with Ethernet the Gnawing Critters in your neck of the woods have damaged it?

Comment: Sounds like a huge EM pulse (caused by the fan motor speed change) is giving your router enough of a kick that it resets itself, or at least resets the WiFi radio transceiver(s) and associated services. You could try contriving a frame or similar to site a few layers of aluminium foil between the heater unit and the TV/router area to see if it helps cut the EM to a point where it is no longer an issue.

Comment: Thwarted by the 5-minute edit rule: If the foil-based contrivance works, you can then either find a permanent EM-opaque solution (e.g. some sort of mesh or cage to put near/around the heater) or get the fan serviced/replaced to reduce its' EM noise.

Comment: "All the involved network devices (Fire Stick, ... are hard wired" You have a fire stick with an Ethernet port? The only ones I've seen have a power input, but are, otherwise, wireless. Are you certain?

Comment: "hard wired via Cat6 ethernet cables" does not preclude interference.  Video streaming tends to be UDP, rather than TCP, so no retransmission can occcur when a packet is corrupted. I've done testing (admittedly in 10G), where it was found that switching a flourescent fitting nearby was enough to cause video interruption where unshielded patch cables were used.

Comment: @FreeMan You can use USB ethernet adaptors with a Firestick, using an OTG adaptor. I have one.

Comment: Fair enough, @SiHa. It would still be good for the OP to confirm that.

Comment: @FreeMan Can confirm that it's connected via Cat6, using a USB ethernet adapter. 

SiHa Yeah, that's what I've been learning. I have a shielded (SFTP) patch cable ordered to replace the current one, just as one more thing to try.

MarkMorganLloyd I'll re-confirm that the Firestick isn't falling back to a wifi connection when I get home, just to be sure. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I think you need to find out which part of the "pipeline" is being interrupted.

- Internet link to router (the cable session)
- Router itself
- Wired or wireless link to device (TV/Fire stick)
- Device itself

Start by logging into router and see what stats and info you can get from it.  Some devices show a "session time" since the last reauthentication.

---

From a wired PC, start a bunch of command prompts, and in each run a `ping` session to each other device.  Run one that is `ping 1.1.1.1` which is on the internet and responds to ping.  
(If you're on windows, you might need to use `ping -t 1.1.1.1` to keep it going.)

Also run a `ping` to the IP address of your router, and another to your firestick and to your TV.

If the item you're pinging does NOT reply normally, then that may be firewall rules on that item.  Most stuff should reply.

NOW with all the devices pinging every second or so, wait till the furnace does its thing, and look what devices loose some packets.

Good luck !

Comment: ping -t might be a better option

Comment: @MikeB thank you - serves me right for trying to remember windows commands from memory.    Remember, its totally okay to edit an answer to fix an obvious error.  (though I think the minimum change size is 6 characters, so you have to add a sentence or fix typos or soemthing else to padd out the change)

Comment: Ran this test and caught a few seconds worth of lost packets while furnace did its thing and the video stream disconnected, on the IP of the FireStick, which is connected to the router via a 6ft patch cable and a usb ethernet adapter.  I'm hoping the shielded patch cables I ordered will help, but won't know until they arrive

Comment: @Tonyx3 I'm not familiar with a firestick so I googled it, and found lots of links like https://www.disablemycable.com/blog/eliminate-tv-interference-from-amazon-fire-tv-stick/   Apparently they're known for **causing** interference, which means they're not well shielded.  If the shielded ethernet cable doesn't help, try grounding one end of the shield.   If THAT doesn't help, temporarily wrap some metal foil around the firestick and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 7):

"I don't think it's a wifi/radio interference issue." It most likely *is* RF interference, propagating along the power line, or even radiated by a piece of wire as short as a few cm. To prove the point, hold a cellular phone near a PC with *wired* powered speakers that *use coax* connectors, and you'll likely hear *beeps* if the phone is moved to the right position.

The first, and simplest thing to try would be to add ferrite beads along the wires *close to* the fan motor and *close to* the control units, such as [these clip-on types](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075G2P5SW). They require no rewiring and should not affect furnace operation.

There are power-line RF noise filters that must be wired in place, [such as this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07ZPWHX2S). It might be best to add such a filter inside the furnace, right at the point where power enters the chassis. To meet electrical codes, and for safety, consider having an electrician wire it into the circuit.

The devices mentioned are just for the purpose of examples.

Comment: I'm definitely willing to give those options a shot.  To clarify, you're saying it could be RF interference from the wiring of the blower motor on the furnace, interfering with the _wired_ ethernet connections between the router and the TV and/or PC? Even from 8 to 10ft away?

Comment: @Tonyx3, yes. Not only can some RF be picked up along a shielded cable, but a short length of wire inside a router or PC, or the router antennae themselves can bring in that interference. From a quick check of the furnace schematic online, it does not seem to have an ignition transformer, so that source of noise can be ruled out. A clip-on ferrite bead at each end of each wire going into the fan and controller should be worth a try -- though not guaranteed to be a fix.

Comment: It's worth a shot. I'll check the wire diameter and order some. Thanks

Comment: @Tonyx3, it's OK if the I.D. of the ferrite choke is much larger than the wire O.D.; it allows wrapping the wire for a second turn through the choke, assuming the wire's long enough. That increases inductance.

Comment: Good to know, thanks! And to make sure I'm understanding you correctly, I should put the ferrite chokes around the AC power wires (both hot and neutral?) that feed the blower motor on the furnace and the main 'wall power' wires going into the furnace's control wiring box?

Comment: Yes, the beads should be close to the motor itself, and close to the controller itself, inside the furnace, and another inside where the power enters the enclosure. Obviously, the main circuit breaker must be **off** while attaching them! See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_bead for explanation. Basically, you want the wire/choke to be a high impedance between ~1 GHz and 6 GHz.